# дольше выполняется запрос с перемеными. oracle

Tags: oracle, долгий-запрос

Здравствуйте. У меня вот такая проблема.

Скрипт выполняется в разы дольше если в него добавить переменные.

Пример

```
declare
begin
   insert into tmp1   
       select fe.uid, fe.type, fe.type_id, fe.id_client, cd.id, fe.amount, fe.doc_num, fe.doc_dt, fe.doc_total, sum(fel.line_total) as lt, sum(fel.qty) as qty from event fe
       inner join event_line fel on fe.id = fel.id_event
       inner join goods dgg on fel.cd = dgg.code and dgg.id = 1111
       inner join terminal mt on fe.uid = mt.terminal_uid
       inner join department cd on mt.shop_cd = cd.cd
       inner join client dac on dac.id_aud = 2222 and dac.id_client = fe.id_client
       where fe.event_type = 1 and fe.type_id = 1  
       and fe.doc_dt >= trunc(to_date('01.05.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy')) and fe.doc_dt < trunc(to_date('29.05.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy') + 1)
       and fel.doc_dt >= trunc(to_date('01.05.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy')) and fel.doc_dt < trunc(to_date('29.05.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy') + 1)  
       and fe.id_trn is not null
       group by fe.uid, fe.type, type_id, fe.id_client, cd.id, fe.amount, fe.doc_num, fe.doc_dt, fe.doc_total
end;

                                              стоимость мощность байты
  INSERT STATEMENT, GOAL = ALL_ROWS             121930  8597    2372772
 LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL    SE  TMP1            
  HASH GROUP BY                                 121930  8597    2372772
   HASH JOIN                                    121418  8597    2372772
    REMOTE                      DEPARTMENT  11  1462    95030
    HASH JOIN                                   121406  8574    1809114
     MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL   SE  TERMINAL    16  2617    143935
     HASH JOIN                                  121390  8574    1337544
      REMOTE                     CLIENT         200 53279   1118859
      HASH JOIN                                 120650  65451   8835885
       HASH JOIN                                90666   149898  9593472
        REMOTE                      GOODS        3      221     6630
        PARTITION RANGE SINGLE                  90583   25389230    863233820
         TABLE ACCESS FULL  SE  EVENT_LINE  90583   25389230    863233820
       PARTITION RANGE SINGLE                   23586   1490348 105814708
        TABLE ACCESS FULL   SE  EVENT           23586   1490348 105814708
```

если в него добавить переменную, то он будет выполняться в разы дольше.

```
declare
v_dt date;
v_date_end date;
begin

v_dt := trunc(to_date('01.05.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
v_date_end := trunc(to_date('29.05.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'));  

insert into tmp1   
       select fe.uid, fe.type, fe.type_id, fe.id_client, cd.id, fe.amount, fe.doc_num, fe.doc_dt, fe.doc_total, sum(fel.line_total) as lt, sum(fel.qty) as qty from event fe
       inner join event_line fel on fe.id = fel.id_event
       inner join goods dgg on fel.cd = dgg.code and dgg.id_gds = 1111
       inner join terminal mt on fe.point_uid = mt.terminal_uid
       inner join department cd on mt.shop_cd = cd.cd
       inner join client dac on dac.id_aud = 2222 and dac.id_cli_client = fe.id_cli_client
       where fe.event_type = 1 and fe.type_id = 1  
       and fe.doc_dt >= :a and fe.doc_dt < :b
       and fel.doc_dt >= :a and fel.doc_dt < :b  
       and fe.id_trn is not null
       group by fe.uid, fe.type, type_id, fe.id_client, cd.id, fe.amount, fe.doc_num, fe.doc_dt, fe.doc_total
end;
                                        стоимость мощность байты
INSERT STATEMENT, GOAL = ALL_ROWS           557721  1   272
 LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL    SE  TMP1            
  HASH GROUP BY                             557721  1   272
   FILTER                   
    NESTED LOOPS                            557720  7   1904
     NESTED LOOPS                           557713  7   1757
      HASH JOIN                             557706  7   1302
       NESTED LOOPS                         557689  7   917
        NESTED LOOPS                        557689  3109    314009
         PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR           370610  3082    206494
          TABLE ACCESS FULL SE        EVENT 370610  3082    206494
         PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR           61  1   34
          TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID SE  EVENT_LINE  61  1   34
           INDEX RANGE SCAN SE  EVENT_LINE_IDX  60  1   
        REMOTE                           GOODS      0   1   30
       MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL SE  TERMINAL    16  2617    143935
      REMOTE        DEPARTMENT                  1   1   65
     REMOTE     CLIENT                          1   1   21
```

не могу понять почему. выполняется на много дольше.

Comment: http://www.foxbase.ru/oracle-programming/plan-vypolneniya-sql-zaprosa-oracle.htm

Comment: /*+FULL(fe1)*/ помог. скрипт выполнился за полторы минуты, а раньше уходило минут 50. Спасибо вам большое, очень помогли :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае с фиксированными значениями оптимизатор предвидит количество записей и учитывает это в плане выполнения. Например он может использовать полное сканирование таблицы, вместо использования индексов, если ожидает много записей на выходе. И когда записей много полное сканирование действительно гораздо быстрее индекса. Если же их мало - то индекс гораздо быстрее.

В случае с переменными выражение компилируется до того как подставляются значения.
И оптимизатор не может строить предположений относительно того, какой интервал дат вы зададите и как много записей будет в выборке. Он рассчитывает на небольшой интервал и решает использовать индекс, что в вашем случае абсолютно не подходит.

В таких ситуациях есть только один выход - подсказать явно оптимизатору, что ему делать. Помогают в этом случае [хинты оптимизатора](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10752/hintsref.htm)

Могу порекомендовать использовать `/*+FULL(fe1)*/`, для подсказки полного сканирования таблицы `event_line as fe1` и/или `/*+NO_USE_NL*/` дабы исключить, часто более медленные, NESTED LOOPS.